# Where conditions generates sql without filter when using repository

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework with LinQ and trying to get all the rows from a database table (filtered in a where statement) using the repository I don't have the where statement on query but if I use directly the database context (with the same where statement) I have it.

**Way 1: Code using repository and linq:**

```
IEnumerable<LabOrder> orders = _repLabOrders.LabOrders.Where(o => 
o.SendDate.Month == month && o.SendDate.Year == year && o.Lab == 
user.CodKais.GetValueOrDefault());
```

Repository class

```
public class EFLabOrderRepository : ILabOrderRepository<LabOrder>
{
    private EFDbContext _context = new EFDbContext();
    public IEnumerable<LabOrder> LabOrders => _context.LabOrders;
}
```

**Way 2: Code database context directly:**

```
IEnumerable<LabOrder> orders = _context.LabOrders.Where(o => 
o.SendDate.Month == month && o.SendDate.Year == year && o.Lab == 
user.CodKais.GetValueOrDefault());
```

Final query result:

[Left Query WITHOUT where - Right WITH where](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVIav.png)

How i can get a query with where statement using the repository call?

Thanks.

Comment: Your repository return `IEnumerable<LabOrder>` which makes all further query expressions to be made by LINQ to objects instead of Entity Framework. Return `IQueryable<LabOrder>` instea or, even better, do the filtering inside the repsitory.

Comment: Why did the query leak outside the repository? The repository's job is to hide such details. A "generic" repository that just acts as a thin wrapper on top of a context is more of a bug

Comment: In addition, don't post code as images, post the code here directly using the appropriate format.

Comment: try to change type from `IEnumerable` to `IQueryable` for `LabOrders`  in your repository

Comment: Yes IQueryable<T>, no repositories shouldn't contain all your queries.  Deciding what data is needed is not a repository concern.  Fetching the requested data and mediating between the business logic and the data store is.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Yes! That is one of basic repository design principle :)